# How to read this PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm creating this array:

```
 foreach($html->find('.position4') as $test) {
$aanvaller['naam']          = $test->find('.col1', 0)->plaintext;
$aanvaller['club']          = $test->find('.col2', 0)->plaintext;
$aanvaller['type']          = 'Aanvaller';
$aanvaller['wedstrijden']   = $test->find('.col3', 0)->plaintext;
$aanvaller['goals']         = $test->find('.col4', 0)->plaintext;
$aanvaller['punten']        = $test->find('.col5', 0)->plaintext; 
$aanvallers[] = $aanvaller;
```

}

When I use print_r($aanvallers) I get this:

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( 
 [naam] => Catalin Tira 
 [club] => ADO 
 [type] => Aanvaller 
 [wedstrijden] => 0 
 [goals] => 0 
 [punten] => 0 )
```

and a lot more values. But the array is filled with the right values. Now I want to ready the values using this:

```
 for($i=0; $i<count($aanvallers); $i++){
    echo $aanvallers[$i]->naam;
 }
```

But when I use this, I don't get any values showed. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to use an object operator `->naam` instead of an array key `['naam']` as in `$aanvallers[$i]['naam']`.  Better would be `foreach($aanvallers as $a) { echo $a['naam']; }`

Comment: Thanks. Works now when changing it to ['naam']!

Comment: I guess that makes it answered. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the inner array as an object. It's still an array too,

```
 for($i=0; $i<count($aanvallers); $i++){
    echo $aanvallers[$i]['naam'];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 for($i=0; $i<count($aanvallers); $i++){
    echo $aanvallers[$i]['naam'];
 }
```

It's array in array, so same addressing.